# Audio plays but the video view is not loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have used the VideoPlayback sample for VUforia Qualcomm SDK and here is how my application flow goes:

When the application is launched, a view comes with a button. When you press on the button the augmented reality view is loaded.

I have successfully been able to create  a new viewcontroller in which I have put all the functions from the VideoPlaybackAppDelegate. It works, and it detects the target and shows me the image and the play button. When I click on the button, in a while the sound starts to play. But the MoviePlayerView is not loaded onto the screen.

I found out that the line which is responsible for this is in VideoPlayerHelper.m:

```
// Add the MPMoviePlayerController's view to the

        // arParentViewController's view

        VideoPlaybackAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [[appDelegate arParentViewController] addMoviePlayerViewToMainView:moviePlayer.view];
```

So I changed it to:

```
(ARview is my customView Controller)

ARView *myview = [[ARView alloc]init];

            [[myview arParentViewController]  addMoviePlayerViewToMainView:moviePlayer.view];
```

With this I am able to play the video with sound. But the Movie Player is not loaded; the sound plays and there is no video on the screen.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I have a similar problem playing remote video files. You can check my post on the Vuforia forum. I hope they will post soon a solution.
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/videoplayback-remote-video

If you find any suitable workaround in the meanwhile please post it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had experiencing similar situación, Vuforia VideoPlayback + Unity + Android, got sound but not video and just notice that in design mode the video url path was wrong (not valid) and when running the App and try to change the path by code produce this issue. Maybe an error thrown on initializing video, not sure yet.
But when replace the url path on design mode with existing one and run my App and again change url by code all is working fine.
Hope can help you

Mariano